# How can I create this centered header with multiple colors?

Tags: html, css, position, positioning

I want to recreate the following header:

[image]

The problem is that the content is centered in the white section. Grey is the background of body and the header is 100% of screen.

What I have now is:

CSS

```css
.top_left {
  background:#3c4d74;
}

.top_right {
  background:#2f3a5a;
}

.top_center {
  background:#3c4d74 url(http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/2816/headerbgo.jpg) no-repeat right top;
  height:140px;
}

#page, 
.top_center {
  max-width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#page {
  background:#FFF;
}

body {
  background:#DEDEDE;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="top-header">
        <div class="top_left"></div>
        <div class="top_center">
            <a href="#">LOGO</a>    
        </div>
        <div class="top_right"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="page" class="hfeed">
        MY content bla bla bla
    </div>    
</body>​​​​​​
```

Which you can see working on http://jsfiddle.net/gTnxX/ (I put max width 600px instead of 1000px so you can see it on fiddle).

How can I make the left side soft blue and right side hard blue at any resolution?

Comment: Make you code readable before posting next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to be very aware of how positioning works.

The `#header-bg` is positioned so it falls below `#wrapper`. It is 100% width, 140px high with 2 divs which both take up 50% of that space and they both get a different colour for left/right.

The `#wrapper` is relatively positioned to make `z-index` work, putting it above the `#header-bg`. Width is set at 600px, and `margin: 0 auto;` centers it.

The `#header` is a simple div which has a height set to it and the background it requires.

Content follows the `#header` in normal flow.

Here is a jsfiddle with the requested behaviour.

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/cRZxN/

This even degrades nicely and lets you scroll horizontally if the content is larger than the screen (something I noticed from the original jsfiddle).

**Edit:**

To make it IE7 compatible I made some changes to fix 2 bugs. I had to add `left: 0;` and `top: 0;` explicitly to `#header-bg` to fix a positioning bug. Made the divs inside `#header-bg` 49% instead of 50% or else IE7 would not resize them properly and make the right div bump down. To compensate for the small gap that created I made the right div `float: right;`.

Comment: You are a champ!! I wish could give more than 1 point. Im glad that i asked , i would never figure out this by myself. Thanks a lot!